# How to incorporate multiple CSS classes into a Flask WTForms?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm using Flask WTForms to generate some Bootstrap 5 forms.  They looks a bit like this:

```
class NetworkForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Network Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    sector = SelectField('Sector', choices=[], validators=[DataRequired()])
```

I populate the sectors dynamically but want to add a couple of classes to the fields so followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739690/how-to-incorporate-a-flask-wtf-form-into-a-bootstrap-form) question/answer which said to add them into the Jinja template as a `class_` which worked with a single CSS class like this:

```
{{ form.name.label(class_="form-label") }}
{{ form.name(class_="form-control") }}
```

The issues I have is when I need to add multiple classes.

```
{{ form.name.label(class_=["form-label", "my-other-class"]) }}
{{ form.name(class_=["form-control", "my-other-class"]) }}
```

But that doesn't appear to work.  Is there any way to add multiple CSS classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the class names into a string, just like you would inside the html attribute.

```
{{ form.name.label(class_="form-label my-other-class") }}
{{ form.name(class_="form-control my-other-class") }}
```